# Identify logic game involving turning things into ladders

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm not certain but I think it was a PC DOS game. I am reasonably certain it was not a Windows game.

It was some kind of logic platform game. You played a fairy, and cast spells that turned things into other things, usually ladders. The idea was to move the ladders around to get past the obstacles in the game. You could not fly or jump so ladder really was the best choice.

But anything turned into a ladder would turn back.

You could opt to turn things into coins instead, which was usually a mistake, but there was this one puzzle where turning ladders into coins was the right way.

I haven't a clue how to find it or what it was called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [F.Godmom](http://www.mobygames.com/game/fgodmom):

> *F.Godmom* is a platform game, featuring a fairy godmother as the protagonist. All the fairy godmothers have been captured, and only you are left to save them. [...] The player's only weapon is a magic wand that can be used to transform objects. [...]

(limiting my quote because I’m not sure how compatible Mobygames’ and Stack Exchange’s terms are).

You can play it on the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/msdos_F_Godmom_1991).

Comment: That's the one. I had a feeling somebody would know what it was.